# personal caption name

Tags: captions

I have a table that I would like to insert like a figure, and I want that in the caption appears "Table 1" instead of "Figure 1". This in one example of what I did:

```
  \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \usepackage{caption}

  \begin{document}
  \begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=16.6cm]{table.png}
  def\tablename{Table 1}{My caption}
  \end{figure}
  \end{document}
```

But it doesn't work...

Comment: As far as I can see, there is nothing which prevents you to use the `table` environment instead of the `figure` environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `\includegraphics` inside `table` environment.

```
  \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
  \usepackage{graphicx} 
  \usepackage{caption}

  \begin{document}
  \begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=16.6cm]{table.png}
  \caption{My caption}
  \end{table}
  \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

As Corentin wrote just above, just use the `table` environment in place of the `figure` one:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering%
  \includegraphics[width=16.6cm]{table.png}
  \caption{My caption}
\end{figure}
```

Not only will this yield "Table 1" instead of "Figure 1", but it will also make sure that the numbering of your tables and figures are separate and consistent and that you can produce lists of them (with `\listoftables` and `\listoffigures`).